# How is the graphic user interface design integrated with the main functional code?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I know you are programming geeks and the "graphic doesn't care", but being a graphic designer myself, I really want to know something about user experience designs,especially on how do they work along with the main executive code.

(1) how are the visual elements such as application window,form,button,icons are constructed and how are they dispatched at a specific timing by the main code?

*For example in web design, if we are to build a form,first we'll have to list out all the input areas&buttons in HTML code, and then we have CSS to give them a little bit style, and finally we would have some Javascripts to make the form alive, but how does it work in general software development?*

(2) I know it has something to do with DLL files such as windows shell32.dll file, but how do they work exactly?

(3) I have tried Process Explorer(and the reshack),but why can I find out graphic resources and the text information through this kind of utility after all? Is this some kind of decompilation?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know all these things? Just curious. If you want to design highly effective UI, I recommend you to read this book instead: "The Elements of User Experience" by Jesse James Garrett http://www.jjg.net/elements/

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm just curious like you. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a palette of tools, just as you do. Our tools are objects that can be combined together. These objects have both appearance and behavior. Behavior may be triggered by events.

Usually we're working atop one of many base [user interface toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit).

Now, here's the important part.

Although we both have palettes of tools, they're different palettes. A quick, attractive graphic design may be costly to produce in software. Software development is partly about balancing costs and benefits. The best software happens when graphic designers and software engineers work together, with mutual respect and open, direct communication.